# php merge array elements into a new key in the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge some key values in an array into a new key => value but in the same array and I couldn't figure out how.

so I have this array :

```
array(
[title] => something
[status] => something
[url_1] => http://someurl.com
[url_2] => http://someurl.com
[url_3] => http://someurl.com
[url_4] => http://someurl.com
)
```

and I need an array like this:

```
array(
[title] => something
[status] => something
[all_url] => http://someurl.com,http://someurl.com,http://someurl.com,http://someurl.com
)
```

oh and if url_2, url_3, url_4 is empty than do not put the separators after url_1 and of course if url_1 is empty do not put the separator before url_2

Comment: What about plain old `foreach` + `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$yourArray['all_url'] = implode(',', array(
    $yourArray['url_1'],
    $yourArray['url_2'],
    $yourArray['url_3'],
    $yourArray['url_4'],
));
unset($yourArray['url_1'], $yourArray['url_2'], $yourArray['url_3'], $yourArray['url_4'])

var_dump($yourArray):
```

Or if you want to make it more scalable:

```
function mergeUrls($inputArray, $filter = 'url_')
{
    $urls = array();
    foreach($inputArray as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value, $filter) !== 0) {
            continue;
        }

        $urls[] = $value;
        unset($inputArray[$key]);
    }

    $inputArray['all_urls'] = implode(',', $urls);
    return $inputArray;
}
```

Comment: if I simply implode it than it will write the separator even if the key doesn't have value an I will get something like this all_url=>someurl,,, or all_url=>,,someurl,

Comment: In that case implement an extra check to see whether the item contains a value.

Comment: Sorry I'm really tired but if I do a check It works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `implode` function.  If you have the url parts as another array, you can easily create the string like this:

```
$all_url = implode(',', $url_parts);
```

The implode funciton only adds the separator where needed.  If the url parts are always going to be a part of the main array, you can do something like this:

```
$temp_arr = array();
$i = 1;
while($temp_url = $array[url_{$i}]){
    $temp_arr[] = $temp_url;
    unset($array[url_{$i}]);
    $i++;
}
$array[all_url] = implode(',', $temp_arr);
```

Comment: I like that your solution is scalable. However, I would edit to incldue `title` and `status`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$param = array(
'title' => 'something',
'status' => 'something',
'url_1'=> 'http://someurl.com',
'url_2' => 'http://someurl.com',
'url_3' => 'http://someurl.com',
'url_4' => 'http://someurl.com',
);

$meta = array('title','status');

$metas = array_intersect_key(array_flip($meta),$param);
$metas['all_url'] = implode(',', array_diff_key($param, array_flip($meta)));

var_export($metas);
```

demo http://codepad.org/SwP87PyL

Comment: Although my answer is easier to understand what is going on, I would probably use a solution similar to this, where I could configure the fields that you don't want to join (implode).

Answer (score 0):

Also try this:

```
$data = array(
            'title' => 'something',
            'status' => 'something',
            'url_1' => 'http://someurl.com',
            'url_2' => 'http://someurl.com',
            'url_3' => 'http://someurl.com',
            'url_4' => 'http://someurl.com',
        );
        $array1 = array();
        $string = "";
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            if (substr($key, 0, 4) == "url_")
                $string = $string . $value . ",";
            else
                $array1[$key] = $value;

        $array1['all_url'] = substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - 1);
        print_r($array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you'll always have those 2 fields on the beginning of the array (title, status), you can have something like..

```
<?php
// Consider you have an array similar to this
$yourArray = array(
    'title'  => 'something',
    'status' => 'something',
    'url_1'  => 'http://someurl.com',
    'url_2'  => 'http://someurl.com',
    'url_3'  => 'http://someurl.com'
);

$newArray['title']  = array_shift($yourArray);
$newArray['status'] = array_shift($yourArray);

// Now $yourArray should only contain the url_X fields so...

$newArray['all_url'] = implode(',', $yourArray);
```

So, [**array_shift**](http://www.php.net/manual/function.array-shift.php) will retrieve and remove the first element of an array, by using it twice, you're removing title and status from the array, leaving you with the url_X fields, and then you can use [**implode**](http://www.php.net/manual/function.implode.php) to merge the remaining array items, using the first parameter as *glue* (see php documentation).